Can I install R binary packages developed for a newer version of R
I am using a program (AquaChem) that is only available as a 32-bit application as a database management tool.
One of the features of this program is a built-in R console; however, because the program is only 32-bit, it requires an older, 32-bit, version of R (4.1.3) to run.
I am repeatedly coming across an error when I try to install packages, as below (note that this is 1 example, but the same issue occurs with many different packages):
  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
scales   1.2.1  1.3.0              TRUE
ggplot2  3.4.2  3.5.1             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/scales_1.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 617139 bytes (602 KB)
downloaded 602 KB

package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMZHYBK\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CRAN/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'text/plain' length 3604371 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

**THIS IS THE MOST RELEVANT LINE**
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'scales' 1.2.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.3.0 is required


Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/ggplot2'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMZHYBK\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

I tried removing the packages in question using:
remove.packages('package')
then re-installing using:
install.packages('package')
and also
update.packages()
all without success.
From what I've read about this type of error (i.e., out-of-date package binaries being loaded), the most reliable fix is to simply update the version of R that I'm using, but this isn't an option for me because R 4.1.3 is the last version that had a 32-bit release.
I looked in the repository at the specified mirror site and can see that the version being called is the latest version available as a binary at the source URL.
My question is: Can I somehow redirect the default repository path so that it looks in the contributed binaries folder for R 4.3 (https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/), or will this cause issues due to version differences between my R installation and the packages I'm installing?
Alternatively, is there a different solution to my problem that you can suggest?
Note that I'm a complete beginner in R, so if I've overlooked something critical or made erroneous assumptions, please let me know.

Basically ggplot2 needs scales v1.3.0, not R. scales dependency towards R is >= 3.6. As a side note, juggling packages to match some version requirement will become increasingly difficult over time.

In general, binaries built for version x.y.z of R will only work in other versions where x and y match.  You'll get a warning if z is higher than your current version, but they'll generally work.
Source packages can work in multiple versions, but they sometimes declare that they require a particular version of R or particular versions of other packages.  It looks as though ggplot2 version 3.5.1 (the one you were trying to install) has declared a need for scales version 1.3.0, but you only have scales 1.2.1. You could try to install an older version of ggplot2; I think 3.4.4 is the most recent one that would accept that version of scales.  But you might run into other restrictions...
So the best advice is to stick with current versions of R.  Then life is easiest.  Maybe the developers of Aquachem could be convinced to update their app?  If not, and you really need to use an old version of R, then you will have to go through a lot of pain to get it installed and working, and then you shouldn't try to update it again.  There are non-free tools (like Posit Package Manager) that can make this easier if you have a budget to spend on it.

I see now that it defaulted to trying to install version 3.5.1 of ggplot2, despite there being a binary version (3.4.2) available. From your answer, using the binary (< v. 3.4.4) would likely address the dependency version issue. Is there some kind of global setting where I can specify to always use the available binary versions of everything, which would hopefully be compatible with each other more often?

You can run options(install.packages.check.source = "no") and then specify install.packages(type = "binary").  If you don't specify the type in install.packages(), I am not sure whether it will try to install a source package even with that option.
